How to write a shorthand for localhost in curl?
I want to write just curl 8000 to work as curl localhost:8000.
I've come up with the following zsh function so far:
function curl() {
    local first_arg="$1"
    if [[ "$first_arg" =~ ^([0-9]{4})(.*)$ ]]; then
        local modified_url="localhost:${first_arg}"
        command curl "$modified_url" "${@:2}"
    else
        command curl "$@"
    fi
}

But obviously, the url is not guaranteed to be the first argument, such as curl -H '...' localhost:8000. Is there a robust existing solution for such needs?

Isn't the URL the only argument you can specify that isn't an option (i.e., an argument beginning with -)?

In general, tag for one or the other of bash or zsh, not both at the same time -- they're not fully cross-compatible in either direction. (Your current code is legal for both, but it's very easy for that not to be true).

I can't see a way to do this robustly that did not depend on reimplementing all of curl's argument parsing. Maybe it's not too complex but it seems like more work than it's worth.
